# Is there way to automatically generate parent values.yaml file from subcharts values.yaml files in helm?

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm, cicd

I am working on a project which has a parent chart and two subcharts. The parent chart, and two sub-charts will be stored in a different repository.
Parent chart - repository-1
Subchart-1 - repository-2
Subchart-2 - repository-3

Now, what I want is to update the values.yaml file of parent chart whenever some changes are made to the subchart values.yaml file. So, that manual updation can be prevented.

I tried reading the helm documentation to find any answers, but wasn't abel to get anything. A solution which I wondering was:

1. Whenever some changes were commited to subchart values.yaml file then a piece of code can be executed in ci/cd pipeline which can change parent values.yaml file.

But this solution at a cursory glance looks complex and messy to me. Or maybe not achievable.

Comment: If you're referring to the actual `charts/subchart/values.yaml` file, you don't need to do anything at all: those values will be used by default whenever the subchart is included.

Comment: It's like I added one parameter in sub-chart values.yaml file and that parameter should be automatically added to parent values.yaml file.

Comment: If you don't, the new parameter in the subchart will still get used.  Why specifically do you need to add it to the parent chart?

Comment: The user will configure the values of subchart from parent values.yaml file. And to test subchart standalone the parameter should be present there as well.